# Delete Rows from pecific Table on Multi-table SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have this `SQL` statement for `MSQL` that selects exactly what I want (I am looking for and trying to remove old data):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reviews` as r
JOIN items as i
ON i.item_id = r.item_id
JOIN master_cat as c
ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE category is null
```

Now, I need a way to delete those rows from only the table called `reviews`.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `DELETE` statement would be,

```
DELETE r
FROM   reviews r
       INNER JOIN items i ON i.item_id = r.item_id
       INNER JOIN master_cat c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE  category is null
```